# Android Google map: Error adding MapFragment in Activity

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

Hi I'm trying to add GoogleMap fragment into my activity

Here is my XML:

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/list_margin"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map_frame"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

And my `LocateusActivity` onCreate method

```
mapFragment = (MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_frame);
```

Don't know what went wrong. I got this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.singPost/com.singPost.LocateUsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #80: Binary XML file line #80: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2977)
```

[image]

Any help is much appreciate. Thanks!

Hi I try replace MapFragment to SupportMapFragment but same error and together with this

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value. Expected 9452000 but found 6587000. You must have the following declaration within the <application> element: <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: what is at line 80 in xml

Comment: Hi I ve add a pic of line 80 in xml file

Comment: are you calling map inside fragment?

Comment: Hi I'm calling map inside an activity!

Comment: is your activity extending FragmentActivity

Comment: Hi yes I'm extending FragmentActivity already!

Comment: try with `getSupportFragmentManager`

Comment: Hi I try replace MapFragment to SupportMapFragment but same error and together with this Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 9452000 but found 6587000.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh Instead of posting it as comment, prefer updating the question for better understanding

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723811/after-google-play-service-update-to-version-13-i-got-an-error) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25154392/the-meta-data-tag-does-not-have-right-value) if any of the solution works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start):

**The XML layout file**

By default, the XML file that defines the app's layout is at `res/layout/activity_maps.xml`. It contains the following :

```
<fragment 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

**The maps activity Java file**

By default, the Java file that defines the maps activity is named `MapsActivity.java`. It should contain the following code after your package name:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

If your maps activity file doesn't contain the above code, replace the contents of the file with the above code, after your package name.

Comment: Of course it is not. It is a nice convention for a simple example like this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figure about the an error in my value.string that return different integer value for google play sevices